# Unable to get the json response from API using curl in PHP

Tags: php, ajax, curl

I am working on a webpage where user will input the number which will be used as a query parameter to API call & need to display the response in webpage. I am running this local mac with php server running on same mac using below command

```
php -S localhost:8080 -t /Users/demouser/my_website
```

I have verified that curl is enabled using phpinfo().

I have below function in HTML file which will be called on tap of button using javascript.

```
function performRequest(todoid) {
        $.ajax({
            url:"api_call.php", 
            type: "GET", 
            data: { todoid: todoid },
            success:function(result){
                console.log("JS result"+result);
           }
        });
    }
```

My PHP file looks like below

```
    <?php
    if (isset($_GET['todoid'])) 
    {
        callExternalAPI($_GET['todoid']);
    }

    function callExternalAPI($todoid) 
    {
        $result = callAPI("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/".$todoid);
        print_r("Result from URL".$result);
        $info = json_decode($result, true);
        echo("Info from API".$info);
    }

    function callAPI($url)
    {
        $curlObj = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "identity");
        curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        if (!$result = curl_exec($curlObj))
        {
            echo "Failed to perform request".curl_error($curlObj);
        }
        curl_close($curlObj);
        return $result;
    }
?>
```

But in Ajax success callback, I am getting

```
JS resultResult from URLhttps://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1Info from API
```

When I hit the same API in browser or postman, I am getting the correct json response. I don't really understand what I am missing here. Can anyone please help me understand the issue? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the following might help - as the endpoint is https you ought to have additional options set in the curl request function to deal with SSL. The curl function below is a simplified version of something I use frequently

```
<?php

    /* https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55339967/unable-to-get-the-json-response-from-api-using-curl-in-php */
    /* jsonplaceholder.typicode.com api experiments */


    if( isset( $_GET['todoid'] ) ){

        $id=filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'todoid', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT  );

        /* utility to quickly display data in readable fashion */
        function pre( $data=false, $header=false, $tag='h1' ){
            if( $data ){
                $title = $header ? sprintf('<'.$tag.'>%s</'.$tag.'>',$header) : '';
                printf('%s<pre>%s</pre>',$title,print_r($data,1));
            }
        }

        /* basic curl request helper */
        function curl( $url ){
            /* set an appropriate path to YOUR cacert.pem file */
            $cacert='c:/wwwroot/cacert.pem';

            $curl=curl_init();
            if( parse_url( $url,PHP_URL_SCHEME )=='https' ){
                curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true );
                curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2 );
                curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $cacert );
            }
            curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_URL,trim( $url ) );
            curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true );
            curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
            curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true );
            curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false );
            curl_setopt( $curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, false );
            curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
            curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36' );
            curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10 );
            curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '' );

            $res=(object)array(
                'response'  =>  curl_exec( $curl ),
                'info'      =>  (object)curl_getinfo( $curl ),
                'errors'    =>  curl_error( $curl )
            );
            curl_close( $curl );
            return $res;
        }

        function callapi( $id ){
            $url=sprintf( 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/%s',$id );
            return curl( $url );
        }




        /* call the api */
        $res = callapi( $id );


        /* process response data */
        if( $res && $res->info->http_code==200 ) {
            /* to debug */
            pre( $res->response, 'Response data' );

            /* live */
            #exit( $res->response );
        }
    }
?>
```

Example output:

### Response data

```
{
  "userId": 2,
  "id": 23,
  "title": "et itaque necessitatibus maxime molestiae qui quas velit",
  "completed": false
}
```

Comment: Thank you for detailed comments & code. It worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Ok first in your ajax call add:

```
 url:"api_call.php", 
            type: "GET", 
            data: { todoid: todoid },
            dataType : "json",
```

After that you have an error in your php. You try to echo an array.

```
$info = json_decode($result, true);   // this line will get you an array
print_r($info);   // this is the way to print the array. Echo is used for strings
```

Just a small suggestion i don't see any reason to return a json and an array with **the same data** in the ajax success. Return your json only and handle the data with javascript.

What you can do is simple use this line of code that you already have:

```
echo("Result from URL".$result); // you can echo that one since it's just a json string
```

Comment: The OP is echoing a string, so setting `$info = json_decode($result, true);` will cause the ajax request to fail.

Comment: Yes he is echoing a json string but then he decodes it and tries to echo that as well. That's where it fails cause he gets a string to array conversion error